# Is there a preferred sequence for buying upgrades in the armory?

Tags: starcraft-2

When playing campaign in StarCraft II there is not so much credits you can spend for the upgrades in the armory. Is there any preferred sequence in buying them?

Are there any more that other worth getting?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Okay, lame answer time.

The point of the campaign upgrade system is that the choice is yours to make. The developers have stated that they want you to play through the game multiple times, playing the missions in different orders, trying different research, getting different armory upgrades. So there is no correct answer for the "preferred sequence" - making different choices will give you a different experience, and a part of the fun is talking with your friends about how you did it differently and trying something else on a later playthrough.

Myself, I picked up enhanced Medics healing speed, increased armor, upped Bunker health, and Perdition Turrets to keep my base defenses alive and well without much assistance. Then I  upgraded my Reapers to go on entertaining adventures with my super-mobile special ops reaper brigade, and am having a blast with it.

None of the upgrades I have seen so far look useless. The only *wrong* decisions you can make are buying upgrades and then never using them - don't enhance your Marauders but then build only Marines - and not buying anything at all.

Comment: I can't agree with this strongly enough.  I like marine/marauder so I upgraded those, but I've already started a second play through around more factory based units.  I can't wait to try rushing ghosts with perma cloak.

Answer (score 2):

Warning: This is clearly subjective.

For most early missions of the game, even on brutal, all you really need are the marine and medic upgrades. Marines and medics cost very little and have a lot of staying power against most enemy units.

Answer (score 2):

Use what you upgrade, keep in mind you're going to end up with a basic base in later missions looking something like Barracks, Factory, Starport, Mercenary Building, then some sort of CC and pool of scvs.  It's basically the 2 Barracks straight tech build for player vs player but with a merc building in augment to the 2nd barracks.

The only difficult mission in Brutal Campaign is going to be the last one.  Generally, you'll want to upgrade mostly all of your buildings then think of what units you'd want to dedicate to for that mission.  A healthy unit composition is great, but keep in mind if you're strengthening certain units, you'll obviously want to make more of them.

In your final mission, you get to choose to shut off the air harass or the nydus harass.  The air harass will require you to create anti air units to stave off, while the nydus harass will have you leaving your base to kill worms.  Whichever you prefer to do, you'd be best probably in upgrading those units.  IE if you want to send reapers or bc's after the nydus or something, be nice to have those guys beastly.  OR let's say you want to stop the air, and you beast up some marines and medics and toss in some better rockets